# passing a new value through multiple layers in legacy code

Tags: design-patterns, java-6, thread-local, legacy-code

I have a monolith backend application. I have a client layer (to call a second service) which lies after several layers of business logic, lets say 3-4 layers of services and other classes. Its in java 6. I have a new requirement to forward a string value to that layer from my controller layer with minimal modification to the middle tier layers.

What can be possible good ways?

1. I know of one -**ThreadLocal**. Is ThreadLocal safe to use in java 6 if i use it.
2. Are there other design patterns that I can use in this scenario.

I certainly can't change contracts for all middle layers now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to construct a java bean initiated as singleton.

Suppose you want to transport the variable "foo" and "bar" from the upper layers to an lower layer:

```
public class TransporterUpperToLowerLayer{

  public static TransporterUpperToLowerLayer getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
      instance = new TransporterUpperToLowerLayer();
    return instance;
  }

  public void setFoo(Object foo){
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public void setBar(Object bar){
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public Object getFoo(){
    return foo;
  }

  public Object getBar(){
    return bar;
  }

}
```

In the upper-layer you call the setter, in the lower layer you can use the getter.

Upper layer:

```
TransporterUpperToLowerLayer.getInstance().setFoo(myFoo);
```

Lower layer:

```
TransporterUpperToLowerLayer.getInstance().getFoo();
```